# How i can create a single list , then create two single lists from it one of them for even numbers and another for odd numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner programmer in my first years in college, I'm working with single linked lists in c++, and I'm trying to write a program without using classes
to create a single linked list input from a user and print it, then I want to put the even numbers
in a new list and print this new list and the odd numbers in another new list and
print it too.
I began with this, I wish if someone can help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {

    int data;
    node* next;
};
struct Even_node {

    int even_data;
    Even_node* even_next;
};
void creat(node*& head, node*& tail)
{
    int num;
    cout << "enter number , (0) to quiet\n";
    cin >> num;

    while (num != 0) {

        node* nptr = new node;
        nptr->data = num;
        if (head == nullptr)

            head = nptr;

        else

            tail->next = nptr;

        tail = nptr;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        cout << "enter number again or 0 to quiet\n";
        cin >> num;
    }
}

void print(node* head)
{
    cout << "the list is:\t";
    while (head != nullptr) {
        cout << head->data << "\t";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
main()
{
    node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
    creat(head, tail);
    print(head);
}
```

Comment: What part are you having problems with?

Comment: Very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070533/segregate-even-and-odd-nodes-in-a-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: If you want 2 separate lists you probably want to create an insert_at_the_end() function that takes a reference to a head pointer and a value. You should have 2 different head pointers for 2 separate lists.

Comment: Remember: Avoid `new`/`delete`. If you can't avoid you need one call `delete` for every call to `new`. You can avoid `new`/`delete` by using smart pointers like `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `Even_node` is unnecessary. Try this: with pencil and paper, take the list `1->2->3->4->5`, and then, *just by changing the pointers,* split it into two lists, `1->3->5` and `2->4`. Once you see how to do that, try to write code that does it.

Comment: _"without using classes"_. Structs and classes are almost the same in C++. They only differ in the default accessibility.

Comment: In C++, all `struct`s are `class`es.  They merely differ in their default accessibility.

Answer (score -1):

First I fixed the problems

- removed dynamic memory allocations and memory leaks
- it's `int main` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

struct node {
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

struct list {
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    node *tail;
};

void creat(list &l)
{
    int num;
    cout << "enter number , (0) to quiet\n";
    cin >> num;

    while (num != 0) {
        std::unique_ptr<node> nptr = std::make_unique<node>();
        nptr->data = num;
        if (!l.head) {
            l.head = std::move(nptr);
            l.tail = l.head.get();
        } else {
            l.tail->next = std::move(nptr);
            l.tail = l.tail->next.get();
        }
        cout << "enter number again or 0 to quiet\n";
        cin >> num;
    }
}

void print(const list &l)
{
    auto node = l.head.get();
    cout << "the list is:\t";
    while (node != nullptr) {
        cout << node->data << "\t";
        node = node->next.get();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    list l;
    creat(l);
    print(l);
}
```

Now you can create a second `list`, call it `even`, iterate through the first `list` and copy all even elements into the second list.